# JMeter - Connect with MySql database without using JDBC Connection Configuration and Samplers

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

How to connect with My Sql database without using JDBC Connection Configuration and JDBC Samplers?

I want to establish connection with My SQL database without using JDBC Connection Configuration and JDBC Samplers as I don't want to keep the database credentials in .JMX file for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put password (/user) inside jmx file, you can load values using property

For example use [__property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) to get value from property instead of hardcoded value:

```
${__property(password)}
```

> The property function returns the value of a JMeter property

properties can be set adding to properties file or command line parameter

> Java system properties and JMeter properties can be overridden directly on the command line (instead of modifying jmeter.properties).
>
> -J`[prop_name]`=`[value]`
> defines a local JMeter property.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JDBC test elements for building a database test plan you can always switch to [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and program whatever you want using Groovy language, in your case your friend is [groovy.sql.Sql](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html)

Example code:

```
def dburl = 'jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100:3306/mysql'
def user = 'root'
def password = props.get('db.password')
def driver = 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'
groovy.sql.Sql.withInstance(dburl, user, password, driver) { sql ->
    sql.query('select name,url from help_topic order by rand() limit 2;') { resultSet ->
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            def name = resultSet.getString(1)
            def url = resultSet.getString('url')
            log.info('Topic name: ' + name + ' topic url: ' + url)
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

[image]

This line: `props.get('db.password')` is reading the value from [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html), you can set the property value using [-J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -Jdb.password=secret -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) article for more information on Groovy scripting in Jmeter

---

You will still need to have [MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)